# Angular disabled property is not working initially

Tags: angular

I'm trying to disable/enable a button based on a condition in an Angular application. The condition is that an array should not be empty.

It looks something like this:

```
<button (click)="doStuff()" [disabled]="myObject.myArray.length === 0">Do stuff</button>
```

myObject is a public property in the component:

```
public myObject: MyClass;
```

In the constructor of the component I make sure the property has an object assigned to it:

```
constructor() {
    this.myObject = new MyClass();
}
```

The class also has a constructor and it creates an array:

```
export class MyClass {
    myArray: MyOtherClass[];
    constructor() {
        this.myArray = [];
    }
}
```

I believed that would make sure that the button is initially disabled, but becomes enabled as I add objects to the array, but I can't get it to work.

However, if I add one or more objects to the array and then removes them, the button becomes disabled. So it is only the initial state that does not work.

The adding and removing of objects mentioned above is done by the user with controls in the GUI. I've actually tried to the the same thing in just code, but then it doesn't work!

The data of the array is shown in a table in the same view. The table is only visible if the array has items, and the condition is very similiar and work fine:

```
<table *ngIf="myObject.myArray.length > 0">...</table>
<p *ngIf="myObject.myArray.length === 0">No objects to show...</p>
```

What is wrong here? Wy doesn't the initial disabled state of the button work? Am I missing something?

Comment: <button (click)="doStuff()" [disabled]="!myObject || myObject.myArray.length === 0">Do stuff</button>

Answer (score 0):

```html
<button (click)="doStuff()" [disabled]="!myObject.myArray.length">Do stuff</button>
```